# What is the problem with this regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following code:

```
Regex scale = new Regex(@"/^(\d+)x(\d+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.jpg)?)$/");
Match m = scale.Match(alias);
if (m.Success)
{
    //do something
}
```

alias contains, `10x10-uu.jpg` and is not matching - success is always false.

What am I doing wrong? :-) Thanks.

Comment: ...the fact that it's a regular expression [is the problem].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delimiters are not necessary in .NET regexes, these are only found in PCRE and JavaScript regexes. Your forward slashes are being treated literally, meaning you get `/^` and `$/`, which make no sense.

```
@"^(\d+)x(\d+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.jpg)?)$"
```

Comment: Well that's annoying. Why couldn't they have a PCRE mode?

Comment: @the_drow: Microsoft always wants to roll their own, reinvent the wheel, yada yada...

Comment: You must admit that they have done it right, though. .NET has one of the best regex engines there are.